# Cross Database Queries are possible

Tags: azure, data-warehouse

Can I do cross database queries from a Azure SQL Database to Azure SQL Data warehouse, I read somewhere that its possible around sql databases but can it be possible in azure datawarehouse and sql database.

Answer (score 1):

It is a "thing" with MS SQL databases, achieved via links using special credentials and external tables (which essentially map a foreign DB's tables to the local DB). It didn't used to be possible in Azure, but it is nowadays.

For more info, see [here](https://sqldusty.com/2017/05/30/setting-up-cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/)